# Aligning Subsections

Tags: subsection, unnumbered-sections

```
\section*{Part 1}
\subsection*{1)}
\subsubsection*{a.}
```

[image]

It looks like this, how can I allign subsections properly according to their rank?

Comment: define "properly". What you show looks correct to me,  what do you want to change?

Comment: Maybe one tab space in front of "1)" and 2 tab in front of "a.". Since it is its sub.

Comment: @BarbarosTeomanKosoglu but most of the time there will be text following the heading, not immediately the next heading, so that will most likely not be directly adjacent to each other. Also, this will be indented in the ToC (where it will show up adjacent to each other).

Comment: that would be unusual. Do you want to also indent the section text? It would look very odd to indent just the heading. Rather than abusing `*` forms of section headings use nested enumerate which will naturally indent nested items

Answer (score 1):

It is more natural to use lists for nested, indented constructs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Large Part \arabic*}]
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\large\arabic*)}]
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\end{enumerate}
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa xs
\end{enumerate}
\item 
Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa Aaaa 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```